# INNER JOIN on 2 tables returns wrong values

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Here is my `SQL` query:

```
SELECT  SUM(amz_event_shipment_items.quantity),
        amz_event_shipment_items.seller_sku

FROM    amz_event_shipment_items

INNER   JOIN amz_event_fees         ON amz_event_shipment_items.id = amz_event_fees.shipment_item_id
INNER   JOIN amz_shipment_events    ON amz_shipment_events.id = amz_event_shipment_items.shipment_event_id

WHERE   amz_event_fees.currency  = 'USD'
        AND amz_shipment_events.event_type <> 'RefundEvent'
        AND amz_shipment_events.posted_date BETWEEN '2016-5-1 07:00:00' AND '2016-5-7 06:59:59'

GROUP   BY amz_event_shipment_items.seller_sku
```

But the returned values are too high... Can't make sense to me...

Am I missing anything?

**Edit**

```
Many shipment_events for each date

Each shipment_event HAS MANY shipment_item / BELONGS TO ONE event

Each shipment_item HAS MANY shipment_fee  / BELONGS TO ONE item
```

Comment: It seems correct. What result do you expect?

Comment: say, for one seller_sku, values expected is 13, I am getting it 15.. for other sku, value expected it 75, I am getting 83

Comment: I need to see some example data. A fiddle would be nice. What results do you expect?

Comment: `quantity` is a column in table `amz_event_fees`, yes?

Comment: no, its in shipment_items

Comment: Ah, so it's the fees table that's multipliying your quantities. Why are you joining with the fees table at all? Do you only want to consider items that have at least one USD fee?

Comment: exactly, although i believe all fee for one item would be in one currency, so  you saying `at least one USD fee` is quite near to what I need

Comment: so even one fee is in USD, that's enough for me... I would pick that record,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is less an answer but an attachment. If I understand correctly, your query returned the wrong results but was reasonably fast, whereas mine (with the `EXISTS` clauses) returns the correct results, but is extremely slow.

So it seems the task of eliminating the duplicates takes too much time.

Two ideas here:

**First idea: Eliminate duplicates immediately**

Instead of joning to fees, we aggregate fees before joining:

```
select 
  sum(i.quantity), 
  i.seller_sku
from amz_event_shipment_items i
join -- join with only one record per ID to substitute an EXISTS clause
(
  select distinct shipment_item_id
  from amz_event_fees
  where f.currency  = 'USD'
) f on f.shipment_item_id = i.id
and exists
(
  select *
  from amz_shipment_events e
  where e.event_type <> 'RefundEvent'
  and e.posted_date between '2016-05-01 07:00:00' and '2016-05-07 06:59:59'
  and e.id = i.shipment_event_id
)
group by i.seller_sku;
```

**Second idea: Pre-aggregate values**

Here we try to aggregate as soon as we can, so as to keep the intermediate result small and not have to look up the events table for every single items record.

```
select 
  sum(i.pre_sum_quantity), 
  i.seller_sku
from 
(
  select seller_sku, shipment_event_id, sum(quantity) as pre_sum_quantity
  from amz_event_shipment_items
  where exists
  (
    select *
    from amz_event_fees f
    where f.currency  = 'USD'
    and f.shipment_item_id = amz_event_shipment_items.id
  )
  group by seller_sku, shipment_event_id
) i
where exists
(
  select *
  from amz_shipment_events e
  where e.event_type <> 'RefundEvent'
  and e.posted_date between '2016-05-01 07:00:00' and '2016-05-07 06:59:59'
  and e.id = i.shipment_event_id
)
group by i.seller_sku;
```

In case there are only few event types, you could also try to get rid of the `<>`, thus making it a bit more likely an index is used:

```
where e.event_type in ('EarlyPaymentEvent','LatePaymentEvent')
```

(In that case it might pay to have an index where `event_type` comes before the `posted_date`.)

I must admit, I don't think any of this will be much faster than the original `EXISTS` query, but it may be worth a try.

Comment: you beauty bro the first one which you suggested (with `DISTINCT` keyword in it) is hell faster than the one in accepted answer...Profiling shows the accepted answer query takes minimum of 26 second to max of 39 seconds with my given test data set...and this one, the first query in this answer gives me a time of min 0.70 and max 0.90... I love that bro...and I am obliged and thankful to you...

Answer (score 1):

You are multiplying the quantities by the number of fees. Use an `IN` or `EXISTS` clause when looking for mere existence.

```
select 
  sum(i.quantity), 
  i.seller_sku
from amz_event_shipment_items i
where exists
(
  select *
  from amz_event_fees f
  where f.currency  = 'USD'
  and f.shipment_item_id = i.id
)
and exists
(
  select *
  from amz_shipment_events e
  where e.event_type <> 'RefundEvent'
  and e.posted_date between '2016-05-01 07:00:00' and '2016-05-07 06:59:59'
  and e.id = i.shipment_event_id
)
group by i.seller_sku;
```

(MySQL is known to be slow on `IN` clauses sometimes, so I am using `EXISTS` here, although I like `IN` better.)

Comment: you seems more close to my required approach, but problem is, 'select e.shipment_event_id 
  from amz_shipment_events e' doesnt exist

Comment: Oh, sorry. That shows I was confused. There is just one event for an item, so my answer is plain wrong. I'm going to delete it.

Comment: LOL ...thanks bro..thanks a billion :) but its killing mysql... that is too say, its taking considerable amount of time to run and calculate the result.. although I replace `*` with `id(my-column-name)` still, its taking too long...while I am still in dev stage, and data is expected to be very large per user

Comment: `EXISTS` clauses should be fast. It's just a quick lookup whether a record matches. If one matches, one doesn't have to search further. So maybe the lookup takes too long here. You should have the following indexes if possible: `amz_event_fees(shipment_item_id, currency)`, `amz_shipment_events(posted_date, event_type)`, `amz_event_shipment_items(shipment_event_id, id, seller_sku, quantity)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113268/discussion-between-zaffar-saffee-and-thorsten-kettner).

Answer (score 0):

Possible that one of your joins is returning more records than you expect.  I would try just doing a `select *` and sort by sku and eyeball the results.

Comment: have done it,that's why I do say I am getting more than expected